# How to start Azure B2C User Flows from Blazor WASM application using MSAL 2

Tags: azure, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c

I've successfully configured the **Azure B2C** service so that a **Blazor WASM** application will launch my B2C_1_Signin User Flow by navigating to `/authentication/login` in my application.

Now, I'm trying to launch my B2C_1_Signup User Flow. When I try `/authentication/register`, I get a message saying that *Registration is not supported*. I assume I am missing some configuration, but I can't find any documentation on how to proceed.

Here's what I've tried:

1. In my wwwroot/appsettings.json, I've tried adding settings to tell MSAL what User Flows to use:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://xxx/yyy/B2C_1_Signin",
    "ClientId": "0000-0000-0000",
    "ValidateAuthority": false,
    "SignUpPolicyId": "B2C_1_Signup",
    "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Signin"
  }
}
```

...but this doesn't work.

2. I crawled through the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication` source code until I found the *Registration is not supported* message. Based on the surrounding code, it looks like it is expecting a value in `RemoteRegisterPath`, so I modified my Program.cs as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("openid");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("offline_access");
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";

    options.AuthenticationPaths.RemoteRegisterPath = "https://xxx/yyy/B2C_1_Signup";
});
```

Doing this launches the User Flow, but it seems to need the **full URL** from the Azure B2C site:

```
https://xxx/yyy/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_Signup&client_id=0000-0000-0000&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5001%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=F1ut2KaRX...
```

Since I don't want to handle the full PKCE exchange (e.g. - create the `code_challenge` and handle the returned `code`), I'm wondering how to proceed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out, by chance?

Comment: @Martijn - Sorry but I never found a solution for this in .NET 6.  Since .NET 7 is due to ship in November, I'll revisit this issue then.  If I find an answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: Is there any option available in the previous versions (.net 5/3) to start the b2c user flows? using Microsoft.Identity.Web

Comment: @SaravanaKumar I haven't found any way to do this.

Comment: @DougClutter seems like .NET 7 is finally giving us the option to specify a login hint which is exactly what I myself was after: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-rc-1/#dynamic-authentication-requests-in-blazor-webassembly

Comment: Curious has anyone figured out how to do this in .Net 7? I have tried in the rc2 version and am able to add a loginHint and domainHint but not able to do the register or call a different userflow for sso.